# How to send serialized data with protobuf over socket in c++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to serialize some data with protobuf and send it over a socket (winsock2). I would really appreciate a simple example on how to do it. I have already checked the Google documentation, but there are no useful examples or beginner explanations.

Thanks in advance for some help! What I'm trying to do is:

**Client side:**

---

```
printf("Sporočilo: ");

getline(cin, line);

if(line == "exit") break;

printf("ID odjemalca: ");

cin >> id;

message::Message sporocilo;

sporocilo.set_bodytext(line);

sporocilo.set_uniqueid(id);

//... some usefull code for serializing data and send it over socket

send(sClient, Message, sizeof(Message), 0);
```

**Server side:**

---

```
WSARecv(Socket, &(DataBuf), 1, &RecvBytes, &Flags, NULL, NULL);

//... some usefull code for deserializing data and getting out bodytext and uniqueid

cout << sporocilo.bodytext();

cout << sporocilo.uniqueid();
```

Comment: What is your problem? What happens when you run your code?

Comment: Well, the problem is that i don't understand how to serialize data with protobuf and send it to the socket. I have tried with some code, but on server side i get message: libprotobuf ERROR c:\temp\protobuf-2.4.1\src\google\protobuf\message_lite.cc:123
] Can't parse message of type "message.Message" because it is missing required fields: uniqueid, bodytext; i would realy aprisiate if someone could writte me this couple of code lines on client and server side and explained to me how it is working, please!!!

Comment: Where are the definitions for message::Message?

Comment: did you think .proto file? package message;

message Message {
  required int32 uniqueid = 1; // Unikaten ID odjemalca
  required string bodytext = 2; // Sporocilo odjemalcu
 }

Comment: this is my serialization (probably wrong): char buffer[8192]; 
   google::protobuf::uint32 message_length = sporocilo.ByteSize(); 
   google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream array_output(buffer, message_length); 
   google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream coded_output(&array_output); 
   coded_output.WriteVarint32(message_length); 
   sporocilo.SerializeToCodedStream(&coded_output);

Comment: and my deserialization (also probably wrong): message::Message sporocilo;
      google::protobuf::io::ArrayInputStream array_input(SocketArray[i].readBuffer, Ret); 
      google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream coded_input(&array_input); 
       sporocilo.ParseFromCodedStream(&coded_input);
      std::cout << sporocilo.bodytext();
      std::cout << sporocilo.uniqueid();

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to serialize is simply:

```
string buffer;
sporocilo.AppendToString(&buffer);
send(sock, buffer.c_str(), buffer.size(), 0);
```

It's hard to say if you are doing something wrong on the receive side without the code before and after WSARecv that you didn't include.

Comment: Well thanks for answer. I was also trying this method, but in this case i can't send č,ž,š,... caracters - geeting error: libprotobuf ERROR c:\temp\protobuf-2.4.1\src\google\protobuf\wire_format.cc:1059
] Encountered string containing invalid UTF-8 data while parsing protocol buffer. Strings must contain only UTF-8; use the 'bytes' type for raw bytes.

Comment: and as i was able to get trough the Google documentation, the most suitable serialization for sending data to socket is SerializeToCodedStream method, but that is simply to much for me to understand how to implement id in my solution.

Comment: "Strings must contain only UTF-8" error is not related at all to how you serialize proto messages. If you are using non-UTF-8 encoded strings, you should declare the field as "bytes" in the .proto file, not as "string". Or (preferably) you can encode your international strings in UTF-8, instead of using legacy encoding.

Comment: Thanks, a have already figured out what was the problem - exactly that what you said. Well, thanks a lot for helping me anyway, i aprichiate that. I have switched to "bytes" and it is ok now. I have one more problem - when typeing message in CMD Windows, i get strange characters when using š, č, ž - and i have also switched to UTF-8. Any ideas what might be wrong???